# Navigation won't toggle

Tags: jquery, menu, click, toggle

I have a Navigation where two of the menu items have a dropdown sub-menus.

At the moment my jQuery you can click on these and toggle between the two to show them but i cant get them to click again and hide (they stay shown). I need them to toggle against each other AND toggle hide and show when clicked on and off.

I can't use an if else statement as I am using click event for mobile/touch devices. I have used an if else statement for the hover state for desktop devices and this works fine

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LPrMy/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      // click show sub menu
      $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
      $('#nav-1 li').click(function () {
          $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
          $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').show();
      });

});
```

Anyone got any ideas how to merge the two toggling features together?

Ive also tried `.toggle();` but the issue still persists.

edit: link with show/hide and toggle being used: http://jsfiddle.net/LPrMy/6/

Comment: Have you considered toggle?

Comment: I have tried .toggle as i said above but the same issue still happens :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your hide() function was somehow messing with the showing of items, and toggle is better in this scenario as well. Here you are :)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          // click show sub menu
          $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
          $('#nav-1 li').click(function () {
              $(this).siblings('li').find('ul.sub-menu').hide();
              $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
          });

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPrMy/4/

Comment: EXACLTLY what i was after! Looking at this more carefully i think what has fixed it is the .siblings as well :) I can acceot your answer in a few mins. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the correct selector.
Try this:

```
$('#nav-1 li').click(function () {
   $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
   $(this).children().next().toggle();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LPrMy/9/

Comment: Heya, not sure if you forgot to update the link but the code in the js fiddle still doesn't work but look at the example above which does. I can get them to toggle but it was an issue of closing them after being toggled. Your answer has helped me though when using siblings and children for classes. Thanks :)